# Matplotlib: scatter plot with colormaps for edgecolor but no facecolor

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to have a scatter plot with colormap for edgecolors but no facecolors. 
When I use `facecolor='None'`, it does not work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radii

plt.scatter(x, y, s=area,c=colors,facecolors='None',cmap="gist_rainbow", alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `c` argument will affect facecolor and edgecolor simultaneouly, the arguments `facecolor` and `edgecolor` are hence ignored.

A solution would be not to use the `c` argument together with a colormap, but instead use `facecolors` and `edgecolors` alone. In this case `facecolors` can be set to `"None"` and `edgecolors` can be given a list of colors to use.

To create this list, the same colormap can be applied.

```
c = plt.cm.gist_rainbow(colors)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=area,facecolors="None", edgecolors=c, lw=1,alpha=0.5)
```

A complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radii

c = plt.cm.gist_rainbow(colors)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=area,facecolors="None", edgecolors=c, lw=2,alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is more elegant than mine

Comment: I think it depends: The solution setting the facecolor using `set_facecolor` actually allows to use the colormap. This would have advantages when changing the data, e.g. in an animation, without renomalizing the colors. For the usual case, both solutions are equally fine, I'd say.

Comment: Thanks for both answers!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `color=` overrides the `facecolors=` argument.

The solution I came up with is to get the `PathCollection` returned by `pyplot.scatter()` and then change the `facecolor` directly. Note that you probably need to increase the line width to see the edges better.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radii

a = plt.scatter(x, y, s=area,c=colors,facecolor='none',lw=2,cmap="gist_rainbow", alpha=0.5)
a.set_facecolor('none')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: if the answer has solved your problem, consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer (whichever one you prefer) to close up that question.

Comment: The proposed solution didn't work for me, but a small modification did: the default scatter appears to have no edgecolor, so I had to do: ```
a.set_edgecolors(sc.get_facecolors());
a.set_facecolor('none')
```
i.e., set the edgecolors to the facecolor first

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been dead for a while, but I wanted to add my experience as I just encountered this same problem.

I prefer Diziet's method as passing the PathCollection object to a colorbar and having it match the cmap used in the scatter plot works exactly as it would if you didn't alter the facecolors.

With the accepted solution, however, I encountered some odd behavior where even after removing the cmap argument from the ax.scatter call the scatter plot edge colormap and the colorbar colormap didn't match.