# How can I draw EMPTY circels surrounding the data points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I would like to add to the plot below open circles surrounding each data point and set the diameter proportional to the values of a 3rd variable. Currently, this is what I tried but the circles are filled and cover the data points. Using "facecolors='none'" did not help.

```
z = df.z # this is the 3rd variable 
s = [10*2**n for n in range(len(z))]

ax1 = sns.scatterplot(x='LEF', y='NPQ', hue="Regime", markers=["o", 
"^"], s=s, facecolors='none', data=df, ax=ax1)
```

[image: This is an example of what I mean with circles of different diameters, but now the circles cover the individual data points]

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [facecolor = 'none' (empty circles) not working using seaborn and .map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727614/facecolor-none-empty-circles-not-working-using-seaborn-and-map) However, in this case, [a matplotlib solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43519640/8881141) might be better than retrospectively modifying the color scheme automatically applied by seaborn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach loops through the generated dots, and sets their edgecolors to their facecolors. Then the facecolors are set to fully transparent.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", size="size", sizes=(10, 200))
for dots in ax.collections:
    facecolors = dots.get_facecolors()
    dots.set_edgecolors(facecolors.copy())
    dots.set_facecolors('none')
    dots.set_linewidth(2)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.scatterplot with open dots]